# Capturing a newly opened window with Selenium

Tags: selenium

I'm using the Selenium Client drivers to run tests built in C#. I'm having a problem where the test navigates to a page and clicks on a button in a form with its target set to `_blank` causing it to open a new window. However the new page being opened returns an XML document and not a typical webpage. Selenium seems to have trouble with this because it hangs when the button is click and the new window opens. No instructions after the `click` method are executed. The test eventually fails with the error `Timed out running command`.

Any help/guidance would be appreciated. I've scoured the net but haven't seen anyone running into this particular issue of the page being opened not being a typical webpage which I think is the core of the problem as Selenium can't really manipulate this new opened window. I would post code except that literally all I'm doing is calling the `click` method on a button which causes a new window to open. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

To tackle the issue of opening in new window. I typically get url of the link which is to be opened and instead of using selenium.click(), I use:

*selenium.open("http://yourwebsite/yourlink")*

This helps me to be on the same window only(which avoids opening new window or tab) and when the testing is finished on this page and you want to switch back to original page you can again use:

*selenium.open("http://whatever/")*

Comment: I switched tasks for a bit but will try this in a few days and let you know. I sort of doubt it will work because the new page simply returns XML and I don't think Selenium can function with the window if it doesn't return an HTML document. Will let you know how it goes. Thanks!